# Why does it say "Are you sure you want to close the Epic Games Launcher? Your installations will be canceled" when I try to close it?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

When I close it, it says  "Are you sure you want to close the Epic Games Launcher? Your installations will be canceled" But someone said if I close it it would resume after I open it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That someone is right. It will resume after you open it again.